# Untraceble authentication popup

Tags: polkit, dropbox

I have this peculiar problem, which I hope some one can help me to solve it.

I use xubuntu 20.05, up to date (on Asus prime x470-pro MB, BIOS V5843)

Every time I login, there is a popup requesting for authentication, saying: An application is attempting to perform an action ...

Investigation showed that there is a file in /tmp with this contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
chown -h -R 1000 "/home/jw/Dropbox"
chmod  -R u+rwX "/home/jw/Dropbox"
echo Done
```

In spite of numerous `greps` and `finds` I was not able to trace its source.
Deleting this file removes the request and cancelling the request removes the file in `/tmp`.

In auth.log there are corresponding lines like:

```
pkexec: jw: Error executing command as another user:
Request dismissed [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/jw]
[COMMAND=/bin/sh /tmp/tmp0b3kwgk6]: 1 Time(s)
```

Now I do remember vaguely that long ago under bionic 18.04, I had some problems syncing Dropbox files that belonged to another user, but I do not remember the details of its invocation.
These popups appeared also before, under bionic.

I was surprised (and annoyed) to see them also in focal. Today I purged all dropbox software and made a fresh install, to no avail.

I inspected all `crontabs` and `initramfs`, also to no avail.

Last hope is to get a pointer from the community.

Comment: you could search the whole drive for the text `echo Done` ... you could get lucky and find the program that creates that tmp file

Comment: Well, of course I did. As well as for other pieces of text in there. Really nobody has an idea what could have caused this behaviour?

Comment: I ran `find /DIR -type f -exec grep -Iq 'chown -h -R 1000' {} \; -print 2>/dev/null` for all dirs except /dev, /proc and the like. This finds the file in /tmp as well as other places where I just mentioned `chown -h -R 1000` (e.g. in an email and my personal file with collected problems). The conclusion is: It must be hidden in a binary file!  Right?